# Parsing HTML Table using Regex

Tags: regex

I am trying to extract the contents of the table using Regex.

I have removed most of the tags from the table, i am stuck with `<br> , <a href >, <img > & <b>`  How to remove them ??

for `<b>` tag i tried this Regex

```
 \s*<b[^>]*>\s* 
(?<value>.*?)
 \s* </b>\s*
```

it worked for some lines and some its giving the out put as

```
<b class="saadirheader">Email:</b>
```

Can anyone help me removing these tags

```
<br> , <a href >, <img > and  <b>
```

Full Tags :-

```
<img src="Newrecord_files/spacer.gif" alt="" border="0" height="1" width="5">

<a href="mailto:first.last@email.org">
```

Thanking you,

Naveen HS

Comment: Do you already know [`strip_tags`](http://php.net/strip_tags)?

Comment: Also, obligatory link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454

Comment: You may also want to learn about the difference between greedy and non-greedy expressions. I.e. in
<b.*?> vs <b[^>]*>

Answer (score 1):

Use the following Regex:

```
(?:<br|<a href|<img|<b)(?:.(?!>))*.>
```

This Regex will match all the tags you mentioned above, and if there are more tags you forgot to mention just add a "|" sign with the tag you want to add, and insert it into the first parentheses.